# Keeping averages updated when nested dictionaries are modified in place

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary, nested

I am trying to store a list of dictionaries with (possibly) overlapping keys and keep track of the average value for each key across all these dictionaries. I have created a class that mostly works, but fails to update the averages if I modify a dictionary in the list directly. Can you point me towards an implementation which tracks both changing entire dictionaries within the list and modifying dictionaries in the list in place?

I would like to be able to access either a particular dictionary from the list or one of the averages by calling an instance of the class like a list or dictionary, respectively. Below I've provided a (perhaps slightly more than) minimal working example of the class that does this.

```
import numpy as np

class ListOfDicts(object):
    """
    Object to store 
        (i)  a list of dictionaries, self.y, and 
        (ii) a dictionary, self.x, which maps each unique key 
             of the dicts in self.y to the average of the value 
             of that key across all dicts in self.y

    """
    def __init__(self, list_):
        """
        self.y - list of dictionaries
        self.x - dictionary containing average of all entries across all
                 dicts in self.y

        """
        # Allow either an dict of dicts or list of dicts
        try:
            self.y = [ {k:v for k, v in i.iteritems() } for i in list_ ]
        except AttributeError:
            self.y = [ { k:v for k, v in enumerate(i) } for i in list_ ]
        self.x = self._update_x()

    def __repr__(self):
        cls = self.__class__.__name__
        return '%r(%r)' % (cls, repr(self.y))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.y)

    def iterkeys(self):
        return iter(self.y)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        """
        Returns true if key is either an index of self.y or 
        a key of a dict within self.y.
        The keys of all dicts within self.y are keys of self.x.

        """
        return (key in self.y) or (key in self.x)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
        If key is an index of self.y, get the corresponding dict. 
        If instead the key is a key of self.x, return the value of x[key].

        """
        try:
            return self.y[key]
        except TypeError:
            return self.x[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, valdict):
        """
        Set the value of a dict of self.y to the dictionary valdict, 
        then update the dictionary of average values, self.x.        
        If key is not an index of self.y, this will throw an error.

        """
        self.y[key] = valdict
        self.x = self._update_x()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        """
        Remove a dict from self.y, then update self.x.
        This does not relabel other dictionary indices.

        """
        del self.y[key]
        self.x = self._update_x(self)

    def _update_x(self):
        """
        Calculate an average of the values of each unique key, k, 
        in the dictionaries within self.y:
            { k: <s[k] for s in self.y> }, 
        where <s[k] ... > is an average over all values of k in 
        each dictionary in y.

        """
        # Find the set of unique keys in the dictionaries of self.y
        keys = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [ set(i.keys()) for i in self.y ])
        # Calculate averages for each key and store them in a dictionary
        temp = { k : np.average([ s[k] for s in self.y if s.has_key(k) ])
                 for k in keys }
        return temp
```

I define `y` as the list-of-dictionaries and `x` as the dictonary of average     values. I've modified `__getitem__` to look first for indices in the list `y`,     and failing that, keys in the average-value dictionary `x`. I've modified     `__setitem__` to replace a specified dictionary in `y` with the new dictionary     and then recalculate the averages in `x`.

Some example cases where I can use the class as I would like are:

```
>>> test = ListOfDicts([{'a':0.5, 'b':0.5},{'b':0.4, 'c':0.6}])

>>> test
'ListOfDicts'("[{'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.5}, {'c': 0.6, 'b': 0.4}]")

>>> test.y
[{'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.5}, {'b': 0.4, 'c': 0.6}]

>>> test.x
{'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.45000000000000001, 'c': 0.59999999999999998}

>>> test[0]
{'a': 0.5, 'b': 0.5}

>>> test[1]
{'b': 0.4, 'c': 0.6}

>>> test['a']
0.5

>>> test['b']
0.45000000000000001

>>> test[0] = {'a':0.3, 'b':0.4, 'd':0.3}
>>> test.x
{'a': 0.29999999999999999, 'b': 0.40000000000000002, 
 'c': 0.59999999999999998, 'd': 0.29999999999999999}
```

The following gives undesirable behavior:

```
>>> test[0]['a'] = 0.0
>>> test[0]['b'] = 0.7
>>> test.x
{'a': 0.29999999999999999, 'b': 0.40000000000000002, 
 'c': 0.59999999999999998, 'd': 0.29999999999999999}
```

I would like `test.x` to give:

```
>>> test.x
{'a': 0.0,  'b': 0.55000000000000004, 'c': 0.59999999999999998, 
 'd': 0.29999999999999999}
```

That is, when I modify the dictionary `test[0]` in place, the dictionary of average `x` is not updated and printing `text.x` returns values that are not current.

I have two questions,

1. is there a good way to fix this problem and have any modifications to a dictionary in `y` trigger an update of `x`?
2. Is there a better way to get at my overall goal of keeping track of average quantities (and other values) derived from a list of dictionaries as the underlying dictionaries are modified?

One particular detail regarding the use of the class is that `x` will be looked at much more often than `y` will be changed, so I would prefer not to recalculate `x` every time it is called.

Please let me know if anything I wrote was unclear, if you would like more details, or if you have any other questions. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: i think 1 simple solution is don't keep `.x`, and just compute whatever average value when you need it via an accessor method

Comment: @Fabricator, thank you for your comment. Computing `.x` every time it's called would be the simplest solution. However, I think that method will be too slow for my needs: In my application of this class, `.x` gets called many times from within several numerical integrals, so I would prefer not to attach any computational overhead to calling `.x`. The average in my MWE is also acting as a placeholder for other functions of `.y` that are more complicated than  the average of `.x`. Moving these function calls to outside the integrals has given me a huge speedup in my calculation time.